# Client certificate authentication ASP.NET Core Docker (alpine) behind nginx

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx

I'm trying to add client certificate authentication to achieve "synthetic mTLS" since current infrastructure is *Internet -> IIS -> nginx -> app (Docker)*. The API is protected by JWT as well. I've uploaded a repro to [GitHub](https://github.com/joacar/client-certificate-auth)

### Kestrel

Running Kestrel on Windows works just fine and the browser prompts for those client certificates that are installed. Selecting any that is signed by a certificate that is trusted grant access.

### Docker

However, on Docker (without nginx), I get the issue with `PartialChain: unable to get local issuer certificate`. I'm adding the certificate as

```
ADD root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

**NOTE:** At my company we use Alpine based image and there is a warning regarding cert. I'll deal with this next after getting standard up and running. See [issue](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/52).

### nginx

nginx is configured for client certificate

```
server {
  ...
  ssl_verify_client      optional_no_ca;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client_certs/root.crt;
  ...
}
```

In this case the logs don't give me anything

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate.CertificateAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Certificate was not authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
```

> Shouldn't nginx stop access if trying to send client certificate not issued by the one specified in nginx?

Could someone help me shed some light how to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, in my case I had to register some environment variables for Kestrel.

Example of container with configured env variables to consume root certificate:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCert.crt imageName:latest
```

More info in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0)